# Detect a frame with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have a predefined reference video frame which I would like to detect in a large number of video files. I test every video frame against the reference frame but I'm not sure what would be the best algorithm for it.

Currently I'm using matchTemplate / TM_CCOEFF and it sort of works but It's little bit strange. It's a 1:1 matching so I'm getting a 1x1 result with a very large number (above MAX integer). It's very difficult to set any thresholds (I need tolerance for videos in poorer quality) because this number is arbitrary.

I'm wondering is there a better approach or perhaps I'm just using it in a wrong way?

// edit OK, I think the issue with threshold was my incorrect interpretation of double value, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED returns 0.0-1.0 value.

Comment: Is the frame _exactly_ the same?  If so, just sum the value of the absolute difference of your reference frame with each other frame. Value 0 wins!

Comment: Well, that's the thing the frame is not exactly the same. Candidate video might be polluted with compression artefacts or even slightly modified (few pixel cropping etc)

Comment: If the size is the same, I would still give this simple approach a try. Lowest value wins now.. :D

Comment: I will give it a shot. Do you know if there is a function to sum up all pixels in an image. Also on similar note is there a function to get sum of a pixels in a rectangle?

Comment: Scalar s = sum(img(rect));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order that you are going to deal with compression artifacts and other things, I have to say that a subtraction approach is not as good as many can think. When you have noise and variation in the contrasts of the image due to compression is better to use a more robust approach, such as correlation approaches, it can be a little bit expensive in time, but much more precise.  I have used [ZNCC](http://martin-thoma.com/zero-mean-normalized-cross-correlation/) (Zero meaN Cross Correlation) and it worked pretty good, I used it in movement detection assuming that the camera was fix, and it worked pretty good.

There are some things, that you can do in order to reduce the computational cost using Integral images, here an [example](http://labvisione.deis.unibo.it/fede/papers/jprl05.pdf). Also I would recommend to use a lower resolution images to do it faster, and there won't be so bad cause this approaches are quite robust to some changes and noise. Finally you can track your wished frame by looking after the highest correlation factor in the frames of the video.

Comment: If you want to know about Integral Images you can click [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#integral)